# create iso from dir having some hidden directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory which is having many files and folders(some are hidden). I tried the below commands for creating ISO:
cd /path/of/content/dir/ && mkisofs -o /path/of/iso/file.iso * **[In this case it is leaving hidden dirs]**

&&

cd /path/of/content/dir/ && mkisofs -o /path/of/iso/file.iso ./{*,.[^.]*}   **[In this case ISO is building with completely unexpected structure]**

Please help?

Answer (score 2):

replace the italicized sections with your CD label and directory, of course:

```
mkisofs -V LABEL -r DIRECTORY | gzip > cdrom.iso.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me just fine:

```
mkisofs -allow-leading-dots -o /tmp/test.iso ./
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is giving unexpected wrong result. I found that dir names and many file names has changed automatically.